# MongoDB Serialization Conventions ignoreifnullconvention ignores false values

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a C# application that writes values to mongo.  With it I have a convention pack

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
            pack.Add(new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true));
            ConventionRegistry.Register(
                "Ignore if default",
                pack,
                t => x);
```

Writing to my database is:

```
var user = new UserModel{
     Name = "Willy",
     Active = false
}
mongoContext.User.InsertOne(user);
```

I use this to ignore missing values and avoid writing every single field in my POCO model.  One of those values, **Active** has to have both true and false in it.  But when I write the values with the Convention pack, it ignores all **Active** that are false.  
To test it, i ran it without the convention pack and writes the values fine, but with the convention pack it does not.  Is there a way to exclude a particular field or tell the convention pack to accept false values?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IgnoreIfDefaultConvention is going to ignore all default values. 
Use IgnoreIfNullConvention instead.

```
var pack = new ConventionPack();
pack.Add(new IgnoreIfNullConvention(true));
ConventionRegistry.Register("Ignore if null",pack,t => x);
```

Another option would be to change the UserModel to use an enum instead of boolean flag. For example, enum UserStatus { Unknown, Active, Inactive }. In this case, IgnoreIfDefault convention will ignore the default value "Unknown" but the rest of the values will be captured.